# Query posts in current category but not attachment format

Tags: wp-query, query, post-formats

In my category.php i want to query posts in the current category but are not in post formats attachments. How do i achieve this?

I currently have the below code that displays all the posts in the current category;

```
query_posts( array( 'category_name' => $cat_name) );
```

I have tried the below code but it has no effect it still shows the same as above;

```
query_posts(
     array('category_name' => $cat_name, 'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                              'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                              'field' => 'slug',
                              'terms' => 'post-format-attachement',
                              'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                            ) 
                    ) ) );
```

Comment: `attachment` is not a post format

Comment: Lol i am just sloppy. I had to change that 

    'terms' => 'post-format-attachement'
Now that code actually works, i must be tired cheers!